# issue with path or with my files with bash scripting

Tags: bash

Frustration.

I've posted this question yesterday , I eventually deleted it because I thought the evening would give me some respite and help me find an answer.

I tried new things this morning but alas no, I'm stuck.

I have the following script that I'm running on `/home/appseuro`

For info: `datenow=$(date +%Y%M%d)`

```
for rep in $(ls -l /home/appseuro/ | grep "^d" | awk '{print $10}' | sed 's/\///g'); do
 for file in $(ls /home/appseuro/"$rep"/"$datenow"/*.tsv); 
  do /home/appseuro/trans.sh < /home/appseuro/"$rep"/"$datenow"/"$file" > /home/appseuro/"$rep"/"$datenow"/"${file%.*}v1.${file##*.}" 
  ; done ;done
```

The aim of this loop should be the following. For each folder within `/home/appseuro/` and for each .tsv files within these folders and also within the folder `$datenow` , I'm calling the script `trans.sh` where I'm using the .tsv files as input and having them on a output on differents files.

I have the following errors , after running it, :

```
/home/appseuro/mens_actu/20140402//home/appseuro/mens_actu/20140402/ek_manu_j.csv: No such file or directory
```

If I'm running on `/home/appseuro/mens_actu/20140402`, the version below

```
for file in *.tsv; 
 do /home/appseuro/trans.sh < "$file" > "${file%.*}v1.${file##*.}" 
; done
```

This script above is doing what the first script was doing but without checking the folders and things are fine!

After 2 weeks dealing with other issues, I want to pull hairs out of my head on this one.

If anyone can explain the reason.

Sorry for any inconveniencies

Best.

Comment: This is precisely why they say _don't parse `ls`_.

Comment: Hi Devnull, I guess I missed that chapter ...

Can you be a bit more precise, please?

Comment: You might _help_ others by also posting what are you trying to achieve rather than having them reverse engineer based on your attempts.

Comment: Fair enough. Let me give all of you more comments on my aim.

Comment: done. Let me know if things are still unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are really trying to do?

```
datenow=$(date +%Y%m%d)
for file in /home/appseuro/*/"${datenow}"/*.tsv; do
    [ -e "${file}" ] || continue
    dir=${file%/*}
    filename=${file##*/}
    /home/appseuro/trans.sh < "${file}" > "${dir}/${filename%.*}v1.${filename##*.}"
done
```

Note that I fixed your `date` format from `%Y%M%d` to `%Y%m%d` since it looked like a typo (`%M` is minutes).

Comment: Hi Adrian, that was what I was looking for. I think I can reverse what you did with what `devnull` gave me as hint.

Cheers!

Comment: Reverse what/why? [This is the link](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) that @devnull was talking about, since I don't parse `ls` this is *exactly* what you should be doing instead ;-)

Comment: for the `%m` , it is probably a typo.

Comment: reverse your logic with the -e option, especially. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Ah, maybe I should have explained that. The `[ -e ... ]` test makes sure that the file really exists before doing anything with it. E.g. in case there are no `.tsv` files the variable `${file}` expands to the literal string `/home/appseuro/*/[...]/*.tsv` and the loop will still be entered, which is not really desired. Alternatively the [`nullglob`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/NullGlob) option can be set, but for portability I prefer the explicit test above. It's just a failsafe mechanism so your script won't explode on edge cases.

Comment: Thanks again. I had a look at the documentation , you and `devnull` provided me with. I found all the options for testing. We should be good with that. : )